# System.ArgumentException: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I'm using the C# code below to populate a WinForms ListBox. I want to hide all System folders however. Like the $RecyclingBin for example. But it gives me the following error.

> System.ArgumentException: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.

Being new to LINQ this is more than confusing to me. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\");
var dir = from d in dirs
          where !d.StartsWith("$")
          select d;

listBox.DataSource = (dir.ToString());
```

Comment: In cases like this, I like to bind to [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)s.  Easier to deal with than strings, and you can use the [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx) to filter them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change:

```
listBox.DataSource = (dir.ToString());
```

To:

```
listBox.DataSource = dir.ToList();
```

`dir.ToString()` will simply spit out some description of the enumerable, which isn't useful.  The error message indicates it needs a list, hence the `.ToList()`.