# Error getting items from Entity Framework using Lambda query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda, listbox

I have a listbox that I am trying to populate with the result of a SQL Server query via a Entity Framework linq/lambda query. I am feeding the query with a value from a combobox.  I keep getting lot of errors like the following:  Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?  I just want two fields to populate in a grid

```
       var pAt = ent.Patterns.Where(p => p.Case_Id == (cbCase.SelectedItem as Case).Case_Id).Select(x => new  Pattern{  PatternID = x.PatternID, Pattern1 = x.Pattern1 });

        listBox1.DataSource = pAt;
        listBox1.ValueMember = "PatternID";
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Pattern1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
var pAt = ent.Patterns.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(p => p.Case_Id == ((Case)cbCase.SelectedItem).Case_Id)
             .Select(x => new  Pattern{  PatternID = x.PatternID, Pattern1 = x.Pattern1 });
```

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: This helps the first part of the problem, but now when I assign to Listbox1.DataSource I get the error

`System.ArgumentException: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.`

But, I found the answer for that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655510/system-argumentexception-complex-databinding-accepts-as-a-data-source-either-an)

Comment: Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655510/system-argumentexception-complex-databinding-accepts-as-a-data-source-either-an

Can you please explain why the AsEnumerable makes the difference?

Comment: @MAkin `AsEnumerable` executes the query, so after that you're working with a .NET collection.  Before that, the runtime will attempt to translate any expressions you write in to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Separate the code parts from the SQL parts.  Entity Framework can't necessarily construct an SQL query using code objects, but you can usually work around it.  Eg:

```
var caseId = (cbCase.SelectedItem as Case).Case_Id;
var pAt = ent.Patterns.Where(p => p.Case_Id == caseId)
    .ToArray()
    .Select(x => new  Pattern { PatternID = x.PatternID, Pattern1 = x.Pattern1 });
```

Comment: This helps the first part of the problem, but now when I assign to Listbox1.DataSource I get the error

`System.ArgumentException: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.`

But, I found the answer for that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655510/system-argumentexception-complex-databinding-accepts-as-a-data-source-either-an)  So, thanks!